# Codeigniter 3.0.6 session null after redirect

Tags: codeigniter

The staging server (PHP 7.4) suddenly not working properly on session after login and redirect to the home page, the session is lost/null.

The system is using CI 3.0.6 and uses $config['sess_driver'] = 'database';

Kindly note that I can successfully login and redirect properly on my local (PHP 7.4) and production (PHP 7.0)

I already tried to update the php.int session.auto_start=0 into session.auto_start=1

and also tried to changed the CI Session.php from ini_set('session.name', $params['cookie_name']); to ini_set('session.id', $params['cookie_name']);

But none of these are working.

I also found out that the ci_sessions data is not inserted on table in database.

Comment: _`I also found out that the ci_sessions data is not inserted on table in database.`_ This could possibly be not enough grants for the user to read the table in your staging DB server . Pls update.

Comment: Hi @PracticalOpportunist, As of my investigation, generally, my server is deleting the session after redirect. The problem has no connection to the framework, tho I am still checking why my server does not saving sessions after redirects

Comment: I already fixed this issue. The issue was not about CI3, it was a PHP configuration wherein the session folder has not enough permission to write. Thank you!